# Error while creating Catboost Pools for Ranking Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, ranking, catboost

I am trying to build a ranking model using Catboost library. I am getting the below error while creating a Pool on my training set.

```
CatBoostError: catboost/private/libs/data_types/query.cpp:25: Error: queryIds should be grouped
```

The columns which I am using to group the rows is an array of strings column. In the examples which I have seen in, they are mostly an array of integers. Did anyone faced a similar issue before?

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue
while using below code

```
train_data = Pool(
            data=input_data[['input_col']],
            label=input_data[['score']],
            group_id=input_data[['query_id']],
            text_features=text_features
)
```

It got resolved after sorting `input_data` with `query_id`